# How to convert []byte XML to JSON output in Golang

Tags: xml, json, go

Is there a way to convert XML ([]byte) to JSON output in Golang?

I've got below function where `body` is `[]byte` but I want to transform this XML response to JSON after some manipulation. I've tried `Unmarshal` in `xml` package with no success:

```
// POST 
func (u *UserResource) authenticateUser(request *restful.Request, response *restful.Response) {
    App := new(Api)
    App.url = "http://api.com/api"
    usr := new(User)
    err := request.ReadEntity(usr)
    if err != nil {
        response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        response.WriteErrorString(http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
        return
    }

    buf := []byte("<app version=\"1.0\"><request>1111</request></app>")
    r, err := http.Post(App.url, "text/plain", bytes.NewBuffer(buf))
    if err != nil {
        response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        response.WriteErrorString(http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
        return
    }
    defer r.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
    response.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated)
//  err = xml.Unmarshal(body, &usr)
//  if err != nil {
//      fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
//      return
//  }
    response.Write(body)
//  fmt.Print(&usr.userName)
}
```

I'm also using Go-restful package

Comment: @DewyBroto I've put in XML response

Comment: To use `encoding/xml` and `encoding/json` for it in the straightforward way, you need to create `struct`s mirroring the format of the XML response. There are probably ways to get around that using `map`s, but I don't know them.

Comment: When I try `fmt.Print(&usr.userName)` it outputs nil to the console

Comment: Ah, I don't know much about `encoding/xml`, but I know it can't write to lowercase fields (nothing outside your package can). I don't know how you do the mapping, but the `Unmarshal` mapping rules are at http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshal if you want to research.

Comment: @DewyBroto yes. I am inputing XML input as a string as it is received from clientside Javascript directly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you need to convert an XML document to JSON with an unknown struct, you can use [goxml2json](https://github.com/basgys/goxml2json).

Example :

```
import (
  // Other imports ...
  xj "github.com/basgys/goxml2json"
)

func (u *UserResource) authenticateUser(request *restful.Request, response *restful.Response) {
  // Extract data from restful.Request
  xml := strings.NewReader(`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><app version="1.0"><request>1111</request></app>`)

  // Convert
    json, err := xj.Convert(xml)
    if err != nil {
        // Oops...
    }

  // ... Use JSON ...
}
```

> Note : I'm the author of this library.

Comment: fixing example : (this works fine)

func main() {
   // xml is an io.Reader
   xml := strings.NewReader(`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><hello>world</hello>`)
   json, err := xj.Convert(xml)
   if err != nil {
    panic("That's embarrassing...")
   }

   fmt.Println(json.String())
   // {"hello": "world"}
  }

Comment: @luizfelipetx Thank you, I fixed the snippet

Comment: tks, but how can I remove the minus sign in front of some attributes?

Comment: Hi @basgys, is there any way to remove fields with `-` from the json output.

Comment: Hi @iamatsundere181, did you figure out answer for your question?

Answer (score 13):

The generic answer to your question of how to convert XML input to JSON output might be something like this:

http://play.golang.org/p/7HNLEUnX-m

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type DataFormat struct {
    ProductList []struct {
        Sku      string `xml:"sku" json:"sku"`
        Quantity int    `xml:"quantity" json:"quantity"`
    } `xml:"Product" json:"products"`
}

func main() {
    xmlData := []byte(`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ProductList>
    <Product>
        <sku>ABC123</sku>
        <quantity>2</quantity>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <sku>ABC123</sku>
        <quantity>2</quantity>
    </Product>
</ProductList>`)

    data := &DataFormat{}
    err := xml.Unmarshal(xmlData, data)
    if nil != err {
        fmt.Println("Error unmarshalling from XML", err)
        return
    }

    result, err := json.Marshal(data)
    if nil != err {
        fmt.Println("Error marshalling to JSON", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("%s\n", result)
}
```