# How to convert XML data into JSON data in Go?

Tags: xml, json, go

I want to create JSON object from a XML document in Go. Right now what I am doing is getting the XML data in struct object using xml.Unmarshall function and then programmatically format a string in JSON structure using fmt.Sprintf function.

This code is not readable and I feel some better way should be there to do it. Can someone please suggest something better.

My current code is

```
var root Root
_ = xml.Unmarshal(data, &root)

fmt.Fprintln(w, fmt.Sprintf("{\"type\": \"%s\", \"action\": \"save\", \"entry\": {\"ads_enabled\": 1, \"comments_enabled\": 0, \"cover_headline\": \"%s\", }}",
            root.Type,
            root.SeoHeadline, //coverheadline           ))

type Root struct {
    Type                 string `xml:"type,attr"    json:"type"`
    CoverHeadline        string `xml:"Head>PageHeadline>p" json:"cover_headline"`
}
```

where data is byte[] object

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert \[\]byte XML to JSON output in Golang](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879570/how-to-convert-byte-xml-to-json-output-in-golang)

Comment: Firstly, please show the code you have already. Secondly, you will want to look at the json.Marshal function to achieve what you're after: http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879570/how-to-convert-byte-xml-to-json-output-in-golang is not solving my problem because the mapping between XML and JSON is not straight forward. I need to make the mapping in struct object itself.

Comment: I'd suggest you show the code you've managed to come up with so far because it's easier to get help from people if you have a fiddle or similar. Otherwise, it will be hard to give you any other answer than "use json.Marshal" which should do the trick for you.

Comment: I am new to Go. Actually Json.Marshal is good enough for what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
import "encoding/json"
```

and the function

```
json.Marshal
```

http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal

https://gobyexample.com/json